# a conceptal vector algebra question

Tags: vector-spaces

using 3 vectors by repeating and extending them we can form a parallelopied. my doubt is what various kinds of polyhedra can be formed using 4 vectors and how to calculate its volume(for parallepiped we have [a b c] formula to calculate its volume right! for more number of vectors whats the formula) ?

Comment: I think you are asking about zonohedra: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron and the pictures there. I don't think there's a formula for the volume.

Comment: Any polyhedron can be subdivided into tetrahedron, each of which has the volume of a sixth of the parallelipiped you are describing.